# Looking for english version of the kalika puran.?

Tags: scripture, puranas, kali, upapuranas, shakta

Looking to read the kalika puran. What is the best unabridged/critical English translation to get into.?

Links or author name will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can check this - https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/kalika-purana-idk854/